# Raw DB query in Laravel takes significant time while making the same query via CLI is fast

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I have a passports table in PostgreSQL. It has ~200 records in it.

In Laravel routes I made a test route and tried to execute this query:

```
Route::get('test', function () {
  \DB::enableQueryLog();
  
  \DB::statement("
        insert into passports (type, number_and_series, expiration_date, issued_by, person_id, updated_at, created_at) values ('russian', '123123', null, '123123', 128, '2021-04-12 14:23:43', '2021-04-12 14:23:43') returning 'id';");

  return \DB::getQueryLog();
});
```

The result I got:

```
[{"query":"insert into passports (type, number_and_series, expiration_date, issued_by, person_id, updated_at, created_at) values ('russian', '123123', null, '123123', 128, '2021-04-12 14:23:43', '2021-04-12 14:23:43') returning 'id';","bindings":[],"time":1864.22}]
```

Notice, that the time is 1864ms, almost 2 seconds.

While when I run `explain analyze`, I got this:
[image]
Execution Time: 0.858 ms

Why it may happen? At first, I suspected that something wrong with relationships since I use Eloquent ORM, but even after running DB::statement with a raw query, it takes a long time.

Comment: Are your app and database on different servers? Could be a network latency issue. I highly doubt it's the app code, unless you have a lot of crazy transaction magic or something happening around the simple insert. Focus on things other than the DB statement itself.

Comment: On the same servers... so yes, very strange. Other queries work much better. I thought maybe it's an issue with cpu/mem, it's a small VPS, but other queries work better. Hmm

Comment: Next things I would check: does a different DB method work better (e.g. `DB::insert()`)? What happens if you remove `returning 'id'`?